# Nodejs assign var once mongodb query finished (callback misunderstanding needing a simple example)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm calling a mongodb query and need to assign the result to a value.

```
   function oneref(db, coll, cb) {
    var pipeline = [{ "$sample": { size: 1 } }]
    var ohoh
    coll.aggregate(pipeline, function (err,oneref) {
        ohoh=oneref[0].code
    })
    console.log('hoho?: ' + ohoh)
    cb(null, db, coll)   
},
```

I understand I have an issue understanding callback, but even checking all hello world examples, I'm struggling.

How to write it in the simplest way so I only assigne the var hoho when the query finished?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting undefined value for the variable `hoho` is because the `aggregate()` cursor method is asynchronous, and can finish at any time. In your case, it is finishing after you're using `console.log()`, so the values are undefined when you're accessing them.

Asign the variable as the argument to the callback within the `aggregate()` function callback i.e.

```
function oneref(db, coll, cb) {
    var pipeline = [{ "$sample": { size: 1 } }];
    coll.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, oneref) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        var hoho = oneref[0].code
        console.log('hoho?: ' + hoho);
        cb(null, hoho);   
    });    
};
```

Calling the `oneref` function:

```
oneref(db, collection, function(err, result){
    console.log(result); // logs the oneref[0].code
});
```

Refer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a better understanding on how callback functions work.

Comment: Many thanks, it does get better. Any tip on how to use this function with async.foreachof?